# Highchart export in Internet explorer

Tags: highcharts

I have a problem with the export function in Highcharts. In every other web browser the export works fine except in Internet Explorer. We use our own export server with Tomcat and PhantomJS however this error occurs when we use the Higchart server as well.

In the screenshot from an export (in this case a JPEG, but I get the same image with PDF, SVG & PNG) below you can see that the values appears twice. In the original chart on the webpage the values appear once above the columns.

Any ideas how to fix this ? I use the latest versions of Highchart and JQuery.

[image]

Comment: Do you encounter the same issue in the official [demos](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/)? If not, could you setup jsfiddle with the issue? Also, which version of phantomJS you use? It was bug in 1.x version as I recall, but should be fixed in 2.x. See [this report](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/3649).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After examining my code I saw that I didn’t have export enabled in my configuration but the export option still showed up in my chart and worked (but not for Internet Explorer).

After enabling export in my configuration for the chart, it works perfectly in Internet Explorer